# Renumbering Cisco 3750X Stack

Tags: stacking, cisco-3750, stackwise

I am thinking about renumbering my Cisco 3750X stack. Currently as it sits, the stack from top to bottom is

```
Switch 5
Switch 1
Switch 2
Switch 3
Switch 4
```

I am wanting the stack to be renumbered to the following without physically moving any switch

```
Switch 1
Switch 2
Switch 3
Switch 4
Switch 5
```

By renumbering the stack will that cause issues with the configuration at all?

I currently have descriptions set on certain interfaces, will those descriptions go with the newly renumbered interface or stay with the physical interface itself?

Will description on `gi1/0/3 - PC1` technically be `gi2/0/3 - PC1` now after the renumbering occurs?

Comment: I'll have to test... I'm pretty sure you can renumber all switches and reload the stack and it works. And yes, descriptions stay on the same physical port even as the port number changes.

Comment: Was wondering if you were able to find anything @cpt_fink?